# Within a transaction on SQL Server (and other SQL databases), are column defaults applied on INSERT or on COMMIT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

Let's say I have a DATETIME column on a table with a default value of GETDATE(). I also have an INSERT statement into that table, which does *not* list that column in it's list of columns (so the default is applied implicitly).

This INSERT statement is in the beginning of a transaction block that overall takes, let's say, 5 seconds to run.

Let's say I start running the transaction at 12:30:00 (with the above INSERT statement being the first statement in the transaction), and it commits at 12:30:05.

In the default column, am I going to see 12:30:00 or 12:30:05?

**Bonus: What about other RDBMSs, like MySQL, PostgreSQL, and Oracle?**

My assumption is 12:30:00, but just wanted to check...

Comment: What do you actually see after insert? did you checked that?

Comment: No, this is a theoretical question, and I'm wondering about all RDBMSs... I can test it myself on SQL Server but not others.

Comment: Concept is same in every RDBMS. column defaults will be applied at the point of insert and not at the point of commit. If tran succeds you see the added row or not at all.

Comment: @Rahul: the question isn't whether the insert succeeds or not, but which time is recorded in the column.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be correct on SQL Server (just tested it, at least with a table variable). I was just wondering if this behavior is the same on all RDBMSs.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that's what I mean to say; time recorded will be the time at the point of insertion and not when commit hits ... conceptually. Open to know if it difers

Comment: Ruslan, to my believe you will see the same result in every other RDBMS as well.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the answers... I figured it would be the same on all RDBMSs but was just wondering if anyone knows of any different behavior - maybe even a bug in another RDBMS (this question should probably be a wiki or belong on stackexchange, and I should've phrased it differently). Because, for example, MyISAM on MySQL has delayed writes; that's just one example where I was wondering what would happen. But the data itself should still be the same (recent as of time at insert) - thinking about it now. Go ahead and post as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Was not thinking to post as answer but added the summary of comments as answer. Yes, you are write; best place for this type of question is `dba.stackexchange.com`.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, the time you will see is the time at the point insertion (`INSERT`) command hits and not the time when `COMMIT` hits. To my believe, this behavior will be same for all other RDBMS as well with the exception about MySQL delayed write on  MyISAM engine as added by Ruslan.